# What's the longest recorded uninterrupted sequence of single color (red/black) in a professional casino?

Tags: records, game

There is a common misconception is that if there is a long period of unlucky outcomes, it's more likely that there will be a lucky one. But of course the probability of each one is identical, and such a long period of same colors is a nice argument against it.

Comment: I doubt records are kept.

Comment: As a coder, what have you found?

Comment: As a statistical problem, it's fairly simple, but that's a question of math, not history.

Comment: @justCal Simulating, or computing such a probability is easy, but real historical evidence adds more social context - people betting on the other color, believing it _must_ hit next now etc.

Comment: Good try but this isn’t the kind of ‘history’ you’re looking for.

Comment: A simple Google search for "longest roulette winning streak" gives the data you are looking for. Since this means that the question is for "easily searchable trivia", I vote to close.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I didn't know about trivia questions, in that case it makes sense to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [casino](https://www.caesars.com/casino-gaming-blog/latest-posts/table-games/roulette/gambling-myth-monte-carlo-fallacy#.WoW7qKinG00) site says:

> Think your number or color has to hit soon? The longest recorded
>   streak of one color in roulette in American casino history happened in
>   1943 when the color red won 32 consecutive times. In a row. The people
>   convinced black had to hit next were absolutely right. Eventually.

---

Interestingly,  I wrote a quick simulation of this, and can get to 29 in a row rather quickly, but to get to 32 it took several minutes:

```
68717891 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 0 min, 2 sec ,  Current longest run=25
68717892 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 0 min, 2 sec ,  Current longest run=26
102946854 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 0 min, 3 sec ,  Current longest run=27
102946855 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 0 min, 3 sec ,  Current longest run=28
4078170601 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 2 min, 1 sec ,  Current longest run=29
4078170602 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 2 min, 1 sec ,  Current longest run=30
4078170603 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 2 min, 1 sec ,  Current longest run=31
7945382548 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 3 min, 56 sec ,  Current longest run=32
7945382549 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 3 min, 56 sec ,  Current longest run=33
15853962961 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 7 min, 52 sec ,  Current longest run=34
15853962962 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 7 min, 52 sec ,  Current longest run=35
15853962963 Flips, in Elapsed Time: 7 min, 52 sec ,  Current longest run=36
```

Comment: Ignoring spins that result in green for simplicity, the chance of any sequence of N spins coming up red is 1 in 2**N.  So roughly 1 in every 4.3 billion sequences of 32 spins should be all red.  The other bit you'd want to make the mathematical calculation is the number of spins in "professional casinos".

Comment: So it looks like my simulation (just a coin flipper) was a little slow, taking 7.9 billion flips.

Comment: @justCal - Computer "randomness" is almost always from an algorithm (IOW: not really random). I've been bitten by this personally. I'd be more interested in expected amount of "flips" before this happens (a prob-stat person could calculate this for you), and perhaps how long you'd have to sit at a single table for it to roll that many times (given how long it usually takes the ball to roll around, bets to be made and collected, etc.)

Comment: @T.E.D. yes, If you don't Randomize the generator to start each run of a program, you can even get identical *Random* results!  This was just a two-minute curiosity code to see what results looked like. At Steven Burnap 's  1 in 4 billion odds, I think you might grow old waiting to get that 32 reds in a row...

Comment: I once had a RNG I was using and modding by 2 to get a 50/50 flip (which coincidentally may be roughly what you are doing here). Due to some quirk in the algorithm that result **always** toggled between 0 and 1. Always. The seed didn't matter. The algorithms are much better now (Mersenne Twister wasn't invented until 1997. Mine was cribbed from the 1984 first edition of [A Book On C](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1836934.A_Book_on_C)), but still I don't really trust them to model randomness properly.

Comment: The default random library in most languages is generally terrible.  For anything serious, you want to use something more robust.  For C++, for instance, you'd want to use something out of [boost::random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_random.html)  But none of this is history :-P